# Show that $L$ is a strict Lyapunov function w.r.t. $x^e=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

> Consider a system $\dot{x}=F(x)$ with phase flow denoted by $g^t$. Suppose $0$ is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point and for all $t\geq 0$
> $$
> |g^t(x)|\leq \phi(t)|x| 
> $$
> where $\phi\in C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ satisfies$\int_0^\infty \phi^2\leq \infty$. Define
> $$
> L(x):=\int_0^\infty |g^t(x)|^2\mathrm{d}t
> $$
> Show that $L$ is a strict Lyapunov function w.r.t. $x^e=0$.

For previous preparation, I have proved that $L$ is well-defined (i.e., the integral is finite). And I noticed that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\ \forall t\geq 0,$
$$
L(g^t(x))=\int_t^\infty |g^s(x)|^2\mathrm{d}s
$$
But I stuck at calculate $\nabla L$, and I have no idea how to use the asymptotically stable condition.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I presume you mean $x_e$ rather than $x^e$

Comment: Could you please clarify your notation? What is $g^t(x)$? Do you mean that is the solution starting at $t=0$ and the initial condition $x$?

Comment: The phase flow $g^t: \xi\rightarrow x(t, \xi)$ is of the IVP: $\dot{x}=F(x), x(0)=\xi$.